# User manager with Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC web application with Azure AD. I would like to be able to add roles to this application using the user manager.

What I want is to authenticate with Azure AD, take that user and add roles to him.

I am unable to do so. I don't want to use Azure b2c or b2b because it's not what I want. I am really out of hope. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is to define the roles in your application. Below is the content copied from official article.

**From AAD:**
The SaaS provider declares the app roles in the application manifest. For example, here is the manifest entry for the app:

```
"appRoles": [
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "User"
    ],
    "description": "Creators can create Surveys",
    "displayName": "SurveyCreator",
    "id": "1b4f816e-5eaf-48b9-8613-7923830595ad",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "value": "SurveyCreator"
  },
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "User"
    ],
    "description": "Administrators can manage the Surveys in their tenant",
    "displayName": "SurveyAdmin",
    "id": "c20e145e-5459-4a6c-a074-b942bbd4cfe1",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "value": "SurveyAdmin"
  }
],
```

**From your client:**
Roles using an application role manager
With this approach, application roles are not stored in Azure AD at all. Instead, the application stores the role assignments for each user in its own DB — for example, using the RoleManager class in ASP.NET Identity.

**Advantages:**

- The app has full control over the roles and user assignments.

**Drawbacks:**

- More complex, harder to maintain. Cannot use Azure AD security groups
  to manage role assignments. Stores user information in the
  application database, where it can get out of sync with the tenant's
  Azure AD directory, as users are added or removed.

See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles).

Comment: Thanks for your answear but I need to set roles in my code, not azure ad application manifest. I need to authenticate user throught Microsoft, then get him in start up, then look at my db and give him roles based on things in db...

Comment: That should be a query for Role-based authorization? It's also included [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/authorize), you can try to play the sample code to get a better understanding.

Comment: I have already saw all links you sent, I am very thanful for your help, but it those links did not helped... I am so sorry to botter you, but it seems like we dont understand each other. I do not want to do anything with azure ad. I see azure ad as authentificatior for user being real. I want to autheticate user, then get him, then look at db, then gice him roles.